# Unable to construct many to many relationship in gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

i'm trying to construct user and friend table with a many to many relationship in gorm
but unfortunely pop up the error

`ERROR: column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)`

I'm expecting to construct a user <-> friend table in gorm with the code below without any issues

```
type Users struct {
    Id           uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();unique;primaryKey" json:"id,omitempty"`
    UserName     string    `json:"user_name,omitempty" gorm:"column:user_name"`
    Password     string    `json:"password,omitempty" gorm:"column:password"`
    Email        string    `json:"email,omitempty" gorm:"unique"`
    Dob          time.Time `json:"dob,omitempty"`
    Gender       string    `json:"gender,omitempty"`
    Friend       []Friend  `json:"friend,omitempty" gorm:"many2many:friends"`
    LastLoggedIn time.Time `json:"last_logged_in,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time `json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}

type Friend struct {
    Id    uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();unique;primaryKey" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Users []Users   `gorm:"many2many:friends;"`
}
```